# Use JS code in vb.net without add webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, vb.net

How i can execute js code in one webpage from vb.net without add a control webbrowser...

ex:
Messagebox.show(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("answer").innerHTML) 'I would this without include WebBrowser buy using Vb.net "Only"

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Using some other kind of web browser.

Comment: You're referring to a `WebBrowser1` in your example..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the excellent HTML Parser here:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

I will allow you to parse html and action items in the HTML code as you see fit.  It is free and open...

Comment: Can't be realize this without use a third party component?

Comment: There isnt a standard HTML Parser included with .NET, that isn't in the WebBrowser class, as far as I know.